# What 器用な真似 means here?

Tags: translation

> 剣士ガフガリオン
> 「いいか、一人残らず殺るぞッ！
> 生きて奴らを帰すなッ！
>
> 騎士アグリアス
> 「何を言うか！
> 奴らを殺す必要はないッ！
> 「ここで奴らを殺してしまっては
> まさにゴルターナ公の思うつぼ！
> 追い返すだけでいいッ！
>
> 剣士ガフガリオン
> 「そんな**器用なマネ**ができるもンかッ！

It's from the game "Final Fantasy Tactics".

I don't really understand the last sentence.

My translation: "Like I can act that skillfully!"

Does **器用な真似** mean "act skillfully" or it means "skillfully pretend"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For もんか, please see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21320/30454). In a lot of cases, もんか expresses a strong sense of disbelief, denial, conviction, or challenge to another person.

This マネ/真似 doesn't mean copying, pretending, or imitation. It means behavior or act. Per [デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%9C%9F%E4%BC%BC_%28%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AD%29/):

> 行動。ふるまい。「ばかな真似はよせ」

Here 器用な真似 means something that requires skills or high level of ability to accomplish. In this context

> そんな器用なマネができるもンかッ！

means "Something difficult like that is beyond my reach!"