# Does に function like は in お前に俺の気持ちがわかるもんか?

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-に

I saw this sentence in this [topic](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21312/%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B?fbclid=IwAR21cQ4-QfFm7mkGpc6W7VwEBkeuy0VR4vtmsTzLPfqWEyuvi7G8QGSqNG0), but I just have a different question.

> お前**に**俺の気持ちがわかるもんか。

Does に here function like は? Because I think the sentence can also be written like this

> お前**は**俺の気持ちがわかるもんか。

Comment: Japanese potential form may seem tricky at first to English speakers. お前は俺の気持ちがわかるもんか is ungrammatical (but お前**には**俺の気持ちが分かるもんか, with contrastive-wa, is fine).

Comment: @naruto I feel none of those answers address the question asked.  istrasci's answer to [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4442/4875) gives typical examples of how Japanese is taught: あの人は日本語がわかる, which is how I was taught too.  To be clear, I don't have difficulty understanding the use of に; what I do have difficulty understanding is why お前は俺の気持ちがわかる is construed as ungrammatical.   Are you saying あの人は日本語がわかる is ungrammatical?  If yes, how? (Particularly since that's how it's taught.)  If not, how is it different from what the OP posted?

Comment: @A.Ellett - お前は俺の気持ちがわかる is not ungrammatical, but お前は俺の気持ちがわかるもんか is at least on the verge of being so. It must be due to もん (もの), which is technically a noun (or a nominalizer). The sentence sounds like it has a topic inside a modifying clause.

Comment: @aguijonazo  OK. That helps a lot.  I was wondering about whether もん had anything to do with it.  Thanks for the clarification.  I hadn't thought of the issue of は being implicitly scoped within the modifying clause.