# Help with translating そんなもんか

Tags: translation

In anime teasing master takagi-san, Takagi says な~んだ そんなもんか after Nishikata claims he can skip a rock 15 times. From what i found online it sound like shes saying i dont believe that claim.

そんな such, that kind of.

もんか As if, there’s no way ~.

But the next sentence is clear nishikata thinks shes implying she can skip more.
15回より上をいくというのか

Can someone explain how そんなもんか is being translated? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

もの/もん is basically "thing", but it has a wide variety of usages, including [these](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010), and it can often refer to abstract things or ideas. Although [もんか can sometimes mean "there's no way"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21312/5010), this sense is irrelevant in your sentence.

Here, そんなもん is more like "(just) that much" rather than "such a kind of thing". なんだ said before it is an interjection that indicates the speaker's disappointment. か is a question marker.

> なんだ、そんなもんか。
>
> Oh, is that it? / Really, is that all? / Huh, just that much?

Another important meaning of そんなもん as a set phrase is "how it is" or "how it works":

> 「努力しているのにうまくいかない。」
> 「人生はそんなもんですよ。」
>
> "No matter how hard I try, things don't go as planned."
> "That's just how life is."